# FSlint Delete Bug

Tags: 16.04

I searched two directories for same file names. Then I deleted them. They didn't get deleted and now if I search those two directories, it shows no results but the files are there, I tried refresh, reboot, reinstalling FSlint but nothing worked. Someone please help!

PS: I'm using fslint-gui, also tried sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it worked after installing an older version of FSlint (2.42-2).

I used the following commands:

removing the actual version:

```
apt-get remove fslint
```

downloading the older version [fslint_2.42-2_all.deb](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fslint/fslint_2.42-2_all.deb)

install the .deb archive:

```
dpkg -i fslint_2.42-2_all.deb
```

to prevent from updating again to the troubled version putting to hold:

```
apt-mark hold fslint
```

and starting the tool:

```
fslint-gui &
```

to activate update again:

```
apt-mark unhold fslint
```

I found this instructions on a German Website: [Kai online](https://kailiveonline.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/fslint-funktioniert-nicht/comment-page-1/#comment-1334)

Hopefully this information will help you.

conplu.ch